# Using NAudio to capture audio from Kinect

Tags: c#, audio, kinect, naudio

I've written the following code which is supposed to capture 4 channel audio from Kinect. However, when I try playing back the file, it looks like the audio speeds up significantly. Any idea on why this happens or a possible solution to this problem?

```
public void Record4channels()
    {
       // recording length = 5 seconds
        int recordingLength = (int)5 * 4 * 16000*2;
          int count, totalCount = 0;

           // sample rate: 16 KHz, bits/ sample : 16, Channel count : 4 
            var format = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, 16,4);

         var audio = new byte[format.AverageBytesPerSecond];

        using (var writer = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter("c:\\kinectAudio2.wav",format))
        {

            using (Stream audioStream = this.sensor.AudioSource.Start())
            {
                while ((count = audioStream.Read(audio, 0, audio.Length)) > 0 && totalCount < recordingLength)
                {
                    writer.Write(audio, 0, count);
                    totalCount += count;
                }
            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the audio 16kHz? I am pretty sure, that your format is wrong.

Comment: From Wikipedia: The microphone array features four microphone capsules and operates with each channel processing 16-bit audio at a sampling rate of 16 kHz.

Comment: Well. I just can tell you that I would guess that your format is wrong. Try out the windows audiorecorder. And then compare the formats.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the number of bits per sample is 32 and not 16.

I've recorded an audio with freenect in linux. Here's the output of soxi:

```
Input File     : 'test.wav'
Channels       : 4
Sample Rate    : 16000
Precision      : 32-bit
Duration       : 00:00:03.68 = 58880 samples ~ 276 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 942k
Bit Rate       : 2.05M
Sample Encoding: 32-bit Signed Integer PCM
```